# Seletores Jquery - Encontrar e trocar classe Css de um elemento

Tags: html, jquery, css, font-awesome

Estou criando uma Timeline e gostaria de aplicar uma iteratividade quando eu clico em cada card/nó.

Gostaria que ao clicar(expandir card) no link na tag `<a>` cuja classe css é "timeline-link" a classe do `<i class="**fa fa-folder** bg-blue icon"></i>` fosse trocada para  `<i class="**fa fa-folder-open** bg-blue icon"></i>`

```
//Troca o sinal de "+" e "-" drill down by row
$('.timeline-link').click(function () {
    //alert("oi");

    icon = alert($(this).parents().prevAll().parents().parents('li').prev().find("li").html());

    //icon = alert($(this).parents().parents().parents('li').closet('i').html());

        //icon = $(this).find('i').find('.mile')
        //icon.toggleClass("fa fa-folder-open fa fa-folder")

        //icon = $(this).find("i");
        //icon.toggleClass("fa fa-folder-open fa fa-folder")


        //icon = $(this).find("i");
        //icon.toggleClass("fa fa-plus fa fa-minus")
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma resposta com JavaScript puro talvez seja mais simples pra vc. Vc pode fazer um `forEach` e dentro do elemento alvo vc procura um seletor específico, no caso o `<i>` e faz o `classList.toggle`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
let timelineLink = document.querySelectorAll('.timeline-link');

function classe(e) {
    let icon = e.currentTarget.querySelector('a i');
    icon.classList.toggle('fa-folder-open');
}

timelineLink.forEach( (el) => {
    el.addEventListener('click', classe);
})
```

```css
.timeline-link {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<div class="timeline-link">
    <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-folder bg-blue icon 2"></i>
        link
    </a>
</div>
    
<div class="timeline-link">
    <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-folder bg-blue icon 2"></i>
        link
    </a>
</div>
```